# TypeError: Cannot read property 'sid' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I'm trying to send off an sms (which works in Twilio's API Explorer) but seems to fail under my node installation. I've just done a complete uninstall and reinstalled with no avail.

Error

```
7 Oct 21:28:37 - [nodemon] starting `node scraper.js`
Free on Xbox One, Xbox 360, PS3, PS4: Tales from the Borderlands (Episode 1)
/Users/rhysedwards/Downloads/insightful/ozbargain/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'sid' of undefined
    at /Users/rhysedwards/Downloads/insightful/ozbargain/scraper.js:39:31
    at /Users/rhysedwards/Downloads/insightful/ozbargain/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:1924:17
    at flush (/Users/rhysedwards/Downloads/insightful/ozbargain/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:408:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:337:13)
7 Oct 21:28:39 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Error with stripped back twilio code;

```
7 Oct 22:24:44 - [nodemon] starting `node scraper.js`
/Users/rhysedwards/Downloads/insightful/ozbargain/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'sid' of undefined
    at /Users/rhysedwards/Downloads/insightful/ozbargain/scraper.js:12:24
    at /Users/rhysedwards/Downloads/insightful/ozbargain/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:1924:17
    at flush (/Users/rhysedwards/Downloads/insightful/ozbargain/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:408:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:337:13)
7 Oct 22:24:46 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Code

```
var accountSid = 'AC*******';
var authToken = 'da********';

var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

url = 'http://www.ozbargain.com.au';

request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var $el = $("a:contains('Xbox')");

        if ($el.length) {
          client.messages.create({
            to: "61448141065",
            from: "+61418739508",
            body: "hey",
          }, function(err, message) {
            console.log(message.sid);
          });
            console.log($el.text());
        } else {
            console.log('hey');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The callback of `client.messages.create` is used as

```
}, function(err, message) {
    console.log(message.sid);
});
```

When there will be error, the first parameter of the callback `err` will contain the information related to the error, and the second parameter `message` will be `undefined`.

Update the code as follow to handle the erroneous conditions

```
}, function (err, message) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle error
        // Show appropriate message to user
    } else {
        // No error

        if (message.sid) {
            // Use sid here

        }
    }
    console.log(message.sid);
});
```

Comment: Sorry that did not fix the problem. Nodemon still crashes out with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sid' of undefined`. I believe the issue must be with how node is accessing the Twilio node module.

Comment: @RhysEdwards Have you used `.sid` anywhere else in the code, if yes add the similar code there also. Also, check if what is the response in `message`

Comment: That's the entirety of the code source I have written (obviously reliant on the modules called in). Not getting any response form the message. Assuming that's due to the crash of the TypeError.

Comment: Have you tried logging the `err` in the conditional there? `if (err) { console.log(err); }`. What do you get then?

Answer (score 2):

You may simply change console.log(message.sid); 
to

```
if(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please expand your answer and explain why this solves the problem. As it is now, it's more like a comment, and those get deleted pretty quick if postet as answer

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are a couple of things wrong on your code on the twilio side of things.

```
client.messages.create({
    to: "61448141065",
    from: "+61418739508",
    body: "hey",
}, function (err, message) {
    console.log(message.sid);
});
```

on the `To`you're missing a + before the phone number, and after the body, you have an extra comma which you need to remove.

Your final code should look like the following:

```
var accountSid = 'AC*******';
var authToken = 'da********';

var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

url = 'http://www.ozbargain.com.au';

request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var $el = $("a:contains('Xbox')");

        if ($el.length) {
          client.messages.create({
            to: "+61448141065",
            from: "+61418739508",
            body: "hey"
          }, function(err, message) {
            console.log(message.sid);
          });
            console.log($el.text());
        } else {
            console.log('hey');
        }
    }
});
```

I tested it here and it worked fine after changing that.

Hope this helps you.

UPDATE:
Try changing your code to just this:

```
var accountSid = 'AC*******';
var authToken = 'da********';

var fs = require('fs'),
    client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.create({
    to: "+61448141065",
    from: "+61418739508",
    body: "hey"
}, function (err, message) {
    console.log(message.sid);
});
```

Comment: good catch on the comma and the plus. Unfortunately it's still failing with the sid TypeError; starting to think this might be a funny node install but can't find it.

Comment: @RhysEdwardshave a look at my update. This has to definitely work.

Comment: Hey @marcosplancona, appreciate the help. Gave it a go and it's still failing. It's quite a peculiar problem which is why I did a clean install of node/npm. Perhaps it's a new issue node v4.1.2? I have added the latest error dump to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your call failed and there is no message object. Replace

```
console.log(message.sid);
```

with

```
if (err) console.log(err.message);
if (message) console.log(message.sid);
```

Then you will see the error message.